# App Android doesn't open web pages on the smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I have a problem, when a try to access a website from my app on web browser it works, but when I install the app in my smartphone, it doesn't do anithing. I do know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you trying to open the website?

Perhaps you are missing [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser), install it and then open your website as it states in the docs:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

You can use `ref` to listen to certain events or close the window programmatically.

Comment: So need I to change the window.open and adequate to inAppBrowser?

Comment: Yes, which is not that hard, just install the `cordova plugin` and then use that code, of course replace `https://google.com` with your URL. If you check the github page you have more examples to use in case you need more functionality :)

Comment: It works for me and I have one more doubt, is about json

Comment: Glad it worked for you, if you have questions about other matters should ask a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $scope.go = function () {
     window.open('http://www.guiafloripa.com.br/turismo/praias/praia-do-santinho/pontos-turisticos/museu-arqueologico-ao-ar-livre');
};
```

```html
<ion-content>

  
  <div class="list card">

  <div class="item item-avatar">
    <img src="resort.jpg" >
    <h2>Costão do Santinho Resort</h2>
    
  </div> 

  <div class="item item-body">
    <img class="full-image" ng-click="go()" src="resort.jpg" >
  </img>
   
  </div>

</div>
  



  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ion-list  > 
            <ion-item class="list" >
     <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-href="{{x.Adress}}" ng-repeat="x in names|orderBy:'Name'" >
      <img ng-src="{{x.Image}}">
      <h2>{{x.Name}}</h2>
      <p>{{x.Local}}</p>
      <p>{{x.Descri}}</p>
    </a>
    
            </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Is the same problem, work on the browser, but not in the smartphone